# Android Push notifications with Google Cloud Messaging Service

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, android-developer-api

I am new in Android development. I have to work on Android GCM push notification. Am search lots of tutorials and videos but none is helpful for me.

Anyone help me to understand and how to work with GCM ?

If anyone have working code or any tutorial that help me to understand properly then please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty straigth forward, this is how it works...
[image]